# Creating toggle groups in Unity 5

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, toggle

I understand in order to create a toggle group, I have to select the game object I want as the holder/parent of the toggle objects, and then in the `Inspector`, click on `Add Component` and then of course select `UI -> ToggleGroup`

Is it wise to select `Canvas` to be the holder/parent of the group, or should I create a `Panel` first and then set the `Panel` as the holder/parent, or...?

Is there a set of guidelines and what might be a good design regarding this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your Canvas. If its a screen overlay type I would advice to create a holder for the toggles, since you might want to have multiple toggle groups. If for example its a world space canvas holding only the Toggles then adding the Toggle group component to the canvas itself shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Uri.  At the moment, it is a `Screen Space - Overlay` canvas, so I created a `Panel` game object and re-named it `Toggle Group` and added my four toggles to it.  But later on, I will have to change this to `World Space` so that I can use Oculus Rift with the application.  This should be OK, if I understood you correctly.  Right?

Comment: Yes it will work fine. There is no difference between screen and world canvas for this approach. The thing is if you want multiple different Toggle  Groups in one canvas then use individual holders for them. If it is just one then placing the component on the canvas itself is fine.